# 'Close' : is not a member of 'Windows::Phone::Media::Capture::PhotoCaptureDevice'

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, c++-cx

i'm working with VS2012, Windows Phone 8 SDK.
I need to access the camera natively.

I have sucesfully created a PhotoCaptureDevice instance by calling PhotoCaptureDevice::OpenAsync, then get the opened device - mCaptureObject - with the help of  create_task() and task.then().

however,

```
mCaptureObject->Close()
```

caueses compile error.

```
CameraStream.cpp(xxx): error C2039: 'Close' : is not a member of Windows::Phone::Media::Capture::PhotoCaptureDevice'
```

here's a link to msdn:
[PhotoCaptureDevice.Close()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.media.capture.photocapturedevice.close%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

i checked the photocapturedevice class declaration:

```
 public : virtual unknown-type Close() new sealed = Platform::IDisposable::Dispose
 Member of Windows::Phone::Media::Capture::PhotoCaptureDevice
 Summary:
 Releases resources that are associated with the capture device.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call `Close()` on an object, you should invoke that object's destructor.  This will happen naturally when the object no longer has references, or you can call `delete mCaptureObject` to force the destructor to run immediately.  (If you do this while the object still has living references, those other references will be invalid and method calls should throw a `DisconnectedException`.)